# Python/mySQL on an Embedded ARM9 Device?

Tags: python, arm, embedded

I have an application where a small embedded ARM9 device (running Linux) must gather information from sensors and then connect to a remote mySQL database and INSERT the data. I have Python 2.5 running on the ARM9 device fine. I have developed a prototype application in Python 2.5 running on x86 Windows and it connects with mySQL and INSERTS just fine. My confusion in this issue come from working with "mySQL Connect/C" which would have to be cross compiled for the ARM processor before being used.

- What is the best way to port or move this DB app onto the ARM device?
- Are there underlying x86 binaries in supporting libraries that must be cross compiled?
- Or, is MySQLdb simply portable across platforms?

Comment: I would not use INSERT directly in ARM device. Instead I would just collect sensor data on ARM device and send it via TCP to a service on the database machine that would do the INSERT it self. That way you have direct control of every aspect and it is easy to manage all communication disturbances and exceptions to make rock solid product.

Answer (score 1):

It should compile on ARM just fine, but first you should check that your platform's Linux distribution doesn't simply have packages for MySQL (if it has packages, it probably has those). If there are no packages it should be no big deal to compile it yourself. How's your cross compiler? Or is the platform big enough to host its own?

Maybe you are looking for http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-sourcebuild-excerpt/5.1/en/installing-source.html

Comment: When you say "compile" do you mean "C" compile to object, or do you mean Python translate to byte-codes?
Cross compiler (gcc) is on an x86 running Kubuntu. IDE is Eclipse. I'm using NFS to mount the ARM file system. I looked at some mySQL source packages on mySQL website. There were all sorts of CMake files and I'm only familiar with the older Make files.

Comment: I guess you're unfortunate enough to be using a board support package with very limited package support, no Debian or apt-get or rpm? (I've used the Neuros OSD BSP) In that case you will have to compile the MySQL client library which is in C.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using SQLite. I have an application running Python+SQLite for telemetry purposes and it works like a charm. It's much easier than MySQL.

Comment: He wants to get the data into a central database.  SQLite won't accomplish that.